# how to execute custom function for each item later using linq deferred execution?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a:

```
public Dictionary<string,BaseModel> data  { get; set; }
```

and I would like to achieve the equivalent of this code which I have working now, only using Linq deferred execution.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, BaseModel> item in data)
{
   T model = (T)item.Value; //each item needs to be cast to T, T inherits from BaseModel
   model.Init(this, personId); //Init is a function I wrote I want to call on each item
   l.Add(model); //currently I am adding each item to a list, but IEnumerable<T> can work
}
```

I started writing code like:

```
IEnumerable<T> l = Cache[type].Data.Cast<T>()
                                   .Select(item => item);
```

but I can't figure out how to call the Init function (each model has one, they all inherit from BaseModel) on every item. I have been reading about predicate delegates and the like but can't find an example of how to do something like (pseduocode):

```
IEnumerable<T> l = Cache[type].Data.Cast<T>()
                                   .Select(item => item)
                                   .RunMeOnEachItemLater(InitWrapperDelegate);
```

In case you are wondering what this is for, I have an MVC project and I am implementing a model data cache.

Comment: Why would you do `.Select(item => item)`?

Comment: FYI, `Select(item => item)` is completely redundant and actually does nothing.

Comment: I copied that from the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx   I wasn't sure if it was necessary but thought I'd leave it in case the guy writing the Microsoft example knew something I didn't about this.

Answer (score 4):

Don't. It is strongly encouraged to use LINQ in a *functional* style - your predicates shouldn't have side effects. This is precisely because of deferred execution - what that means is that the lambdas you pass to LINQ methods only get executed when they are needed, if at all.

If you want to have sure some side-effect gets called on elements of your `IEnumerable`, use `foreach`:

```
foreach (var model in Cache[type].Data.Select(i=>i.Value).Cast<T>()) {
    model.Init(...);
}
```

Even then I'd consider caching the result of the LINQ expression in a field or a variable if you need objects you know are initialised:

```
var models = Cache[type].Data.Select(i=>i.Value).Cast<T>().ToArray();
foreach (var model in models) {
    ...
}
```

The reason for this is that an `IEnumerable` isn't guaranteed to return the same items every time it's enumerated. Obviously it will if the underlying type is a collection, but if you know it is you should use `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable` to express this.

If you can't make `Init` idempotent so that it can be reexecuted everytime you fetch things from the cache, you should probably init your models when you add them to the cache, or otherwise clean up their lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`List(T).ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method like this:

```
var l = Cache[type].Data.Cast<T>().ToList().ForEach(InitWrapperDelegate);
```

Comment: Calling ToList will causes it to go through each item in the list immediately to create the list...  I want to defer this until additional filters are applied to it later so I don't make multiple passes through this huge dataset if I can avoid it.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda overlooked the deferred execution bit :P I wouldn't recommend doing manipulation on the objects, there is a reason why the `ForEach` method is on `List<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>` :)

Comment: @pilavdzice If you want to *avoid* multiple passes, using `IEnumerable` is the wrong design choice to begin with, unless you absolutely make sure to only cause the enumeration once. Caching results is how you prevent multiple enumerations.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to convert your pseudo-code to real code?

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<T> RunMeOnEachItemLater(this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
                                                    Action<T> action)
  {
      foreach(T item in sequence)
      {
         action(item);
         yield return item;
      }
  }
}
```

Now you can execute custom function for each item later using LINQ deferred execution:

```
IEnumerable<BaseModel> l = Cache[type].Data.Cast<BaseModel>()
                                           .RunMeOnEachItemLater(m => m.Init());
```

Answer (score -1):

The functional equivalent would be:

```
var list = data.Values.Cast<T>()
    .Select(x=>
    {
        x.Init(this, personId); 
        return x;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Note that you can remove the `.ToList()` to return an `IEnumerable<T>` and `Init` calls would run later when the list is being enumerated.

Comment: I may not be understanding this answer, so, could: IEnumerable<T> t = Data.Cast<T>().Select(item => (T)item.CallInit(this,personId)); work?

Comment: Misunderstood the question, thinking the OP was trying to Init asynchronously while adding to list. Now editted the answer to give precisely what is asked for.